# Is the claim that Python methods that use dot notation e.g. `.sort()` don't work on types other than string true?

Tags: python, methods, syntax

When i was studying Python course of Codecademy, they said 'Methods that use dot notation only work with strings',
so... Is .sort() method only working in String type?, or Can it sort with other types? (int, float, etc)

Comment: `.sort` can be used on a list on integers as well. Read this answer - http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5170307264a7402d9a0012f5

Comment: That sentence is highly misleading, and out of context downright false.

Comment: I'm not sure what sense this might have made in context, but reading it here it's just not true. All methods are called as object.method() in python

Comment: @JonKiparsky: See [here](http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/536096db631fe9dd2b0004cb), "It would be more accurate to state that the methods that use dot notation in the exercises in this particular section only work with strings. [...] On the other hand, some built-in functions, such as len, can work with multiple types, such as strings and lists."

Comment: @Amadan Okay, thanks. Yeah, wow, that's terrible. Another reason to avoid codecademy like an ebola milkshake

Comment: Thanks @Amadan and all, I understand about Dot notation.

Comment: strings don't even have a `.sort()` method

Comment: Wow, that statement is not even true in the sense "strings happen to have methods and numerical types don't", even if you're more likely to see `"foo bar".split()` than `3.1415.is_integer()`.

Comment: I retitled this to *"Do Python methods that use dot notation e.g. `.sort()` work on types other than string?"* because that's what it seems to be asking, based on that woeful claim from the offending site . And yes, sadly there are lots of bad Python courses and blogs out there, so when you read something that sounds dodgy or conflicts with your understanding, fire up a shell and check it for yourself, and if it's wrong, drop that resource like a dead donkey, and try to have it corrected/ taken down/ shunned. ("Don't trust, and verify", if you will)

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you quickly try it yourself?

```
>>> l = ['c', 'b', 'a']        
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l = [3, 2, 1]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: This is probably the most important thing you can learn as a python programmer: if you're not sure, investigate the behavior in the interpreter. You can answer almost any question this way.

Comment: If you try this and get a `SyntaxError`, Make sure you're using `l` and not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually string or string type can't be sorted using `sort()`. For example if you choose to do like the following

```
name = "hello"
print name.sort()
```

then it'll throw an error.But still if you really like to sort string or string types then try using `sorted()` as shown below.

```
name = "hello"
print sorted(name)
```

output:

```
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Note: Upper case letters take the precedence over the lower case letters while sorting.